# read() and write() non text files in chunks in C

Tags: c, file, unix, tcp, client-server

I have a client server program in which i read the file from the server to the client in chunks, over TCP. However, not all chunks being sent are of the size I have given. Some of them are less than the requested size or even 1.
This is my server side code for reading from the file and writing to socket
    `rd=read(filed, buffer,128);`
    `write(socketd,buffer,128);`

This true for only non text files. On using a txt file, it works perfectly, but fails for pdfs, ppts, images. Is there any way to read these non text files in chunks?

Sample of size in bytes being read in each iteration for a pdf file
128
128
128
128
116
128
128
36

Comment: TCP doesn't have message boundaries. If you need to structure the messages, you have to do that in the data, not rely on `read()` returning the same size that `write()` sent.

Comment: Why is it a problem that it returns less than the requested size? Just copy whatever was returned into the file, and go back into the loop.

Comment: My `read` is for reading the file contents, the `write` writes to the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I was using strlen(buffer) which gave those numbers. The integer returned by read() was 128, as desired.

Comment: That explains why it seemed to work for text files, they don't have embedded null bytes. Although you're very lucky that it didn't report sizes *larger* than 128, since `read()` doesn't add a null terminator. It's just chance that whatever happened to be after the buffer in memory started with 0 byte.

Comment: But it should have failed for the last read of the text file, the part of the buffer after the last portion read from the file should contain what was left over from the previous read, so it will return 128 instead of the shorter amount.

Comment: You should put the original code into the question so it shows what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should only write the amount that was actually read from the file. If the size of the file isn't a multiple of 128, then the last read can't return 128 bytes, it just returns what's left in the file. Use `rd` as the amount to write to the socket.

```
while ((rd = read(filed, buffer, 128)) > 0) {
    write(socketd, buffer, rd);
}
```

Comment: I am already doing this step. Its that in the iterations not near the end too that the complete chunk isn't being read. This issue is specifically for non text files. Text files work perfectly, so its probably something to do with the file type I guess, but can't find anything stating so.

Comment: What operating system? Unix doesn't make any distinction between text and non-text files.

Comment: Im using Gentoo. Hence the confusion, technically the file should be read as is, without any such distinction

Comment: I agree, it should. But what difference does it make? `read()` is always allowed to return less than the maximum, and the program should work correctly regardless.

Comment: That is there, the program does what it needs to, but this just increases the number of times written to the socket.

Comment: It shouldn't be a significant problem, the network driver should combine them into larger packets.

Comment: Yeah. I'll leave this question open in case anyone has faced such an issue. Thanks